# multiple network interfaces on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet-connection

My PC is connected to internet over 2 network interfaces, I want to make some application use one interface and not the other.

How to do it ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool named [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip).

First download the utility. Then go to Settings > Network and Internet > Change adapter options. Double click the network adapter/interface and click Details. Copy the IPv4 address of the adapter/interface. Then open Command Prompt as administrator and use `cd "ForceBindIP Filepath"`. Then use `ForceBindIP ip_address "application_path"`.

Hope that helps

Comment: ty it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome! My pleasure